# Группировка в sql запросе по максимальному значению

Tags: oracle, mysql, postgresql, sql-server, sql

У меня есть таблица:

- номер
- сотрудник
- дата(пропуска)

Мне нужно в запросе узнать номера последнего пропуска по каждому сотруднику, пишу запрос: `select max(data),nomer from propuski group by nomer ...`(работает). A теперь мне нужно эти данные использовать в другом запросе, просто написать типа `select ... where nomer in (этот_запрос)` не получается, т.к. этот запрос возвращает 2 столбца.

1. Как можно сослаться именно на столбец `nomer`
2. И можно ли в первом запросе вывести только список номеров? (т.е. тут меня не интересуют даты, а нужны именно номера по каждому сотруднику)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `select max(data),nomer from propuski group by nomer`

Этим запросом вы получаете списки *всех* уникальный номеров с максимальной датой, а не по каждому сотруднику. А если у вас поле nomer уникально, то этот запрос будет эквивалентным запросу `select data, nomer from propuski`

В общем случае ваша задача решается следующим образом:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.employer, p.nomer
FROM propuski p
JOIN (SELECT MAX(data) as max_data, employer FROM propuski GROUP BY employer) m
  ON p.data = m.max_data AND p.employer = m.employer
```

В некоторых СУБД запрос можно будет упростить. К примеру в Postgres для этого можно использовать [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html).

Comment: Спасибо, частично понял... но в join-e только дата и сотрудник...а номера нет...я пытался добавить, но с группировкой проблема...
Ещё подобный вопрос
http://hashcode.ru/questions/76315
С этим я понял....